# How to cast an element of a 3D Object array to an Integer/string etc

Tags: java, arrays, casting

So I'm trying to make a minesweeper game using arrays. I'm using 2D arrays to make the board, and I have one setup that generates mines(board), and another that compares to board that generates the numbers. I want to use 3 dimensions, the second index of the third being strings so that it displays the second index of the third ([][][1]) with underscores or dots or whatever and I can move up to the first index (that contains the numbers and mines which are ints or whatever) when the user selects a given coordinate. I'm running into issues trying to manipulate the coordinates to generate the numbers since I'm forced to use the Object type when using multiple data types within the array. getting the error

"The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int"

using (Integer) doesn't fix it. As you can see below;

```
    Random random = new Random();

    Object board[][][] = new Object[11][11][2];
    Object playBoard[][][] = new Object [11][11][2];
    int randomNums[] = new int[]{0, 0, 9, 0, 0};        

    //generating mines. 
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(randomNums.length);
            board[j][i][0] = randomNums[randomIndex];
        }
    }

    //printing mine board for developing
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[j][i][0] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    //making numbers on board
    for(int i=1; i<11; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<11; j++) {
            //this creates the numbers on the playBoard
            if((Integer)board[j][i][0] == 9) {        // casting works fine here.
                (Integer)playBoard[j-1][i-1][0] += 1; //ERROR here and the next lines.
                playBoard[j][i-1][0] += 1;
                playBoard[j+1][i-1][0] += 1;
                playBoard[j-1][i][0] += 1;
                playBoard[j+1][i][0] += 1;
                playBoard[j-1][i+1][0] += 1;
                playBoard[j][i+1][0] += 1; 
                playBoard[j+1][i+1][0] += 1; 

            }
        }
    }
    //printing number board
    System.out.println("\n   a b c d e f g h i j \n");
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                System.out.print(i + "  ");
                for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                    if(board[j][i][0] == 9)
                    {
                        System.out.print("x ");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(playBoard[j][i][1] + " ");
                    }       
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
     }
```

The way it works, is the first depth or whatever in the array(j, in my loops) is the width, and the second(i) is the height. I iterate through each coordinate, and if the corresponding value of board is 9 (a mine) then it adds 1 to the coordinates around the current index. It works totally fine in 2 dimensions but I wanted to try to make it work using 3 with strings on the second-third dimension ([][][1]) so I can have it be a bit more customised in it's presentation, if that makes sense. Code is kind of sloppy but you get the gist. I'm a first year and haven't gotten to ArrayLists or whatever you call it, would that be a better approach or could this work? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you forced to use multiple data types? Rather then using an `Object` array `Object board[][][] = new Object[11][11][2];` you should swap to an `Integer` array like so `Integer board[][][] = new Integer[11][11][2];`. If you really need multiple jata types then either cast the data to an int before using `+=`, or use a 2D array with your own custom object that stores an int along with the other data that you need, then you can use get/set methods to update the data.

Comment: For assiginnig "in place" don't use `+=`, that does not work with objects, you instead need to use just `=` and cast it correctly after the operator `playBoard[j-1][i-1][0] = (Integer)playBoard[j-1][i-1][0] + 1;`

Comment: Why not use ``byte[][][] board``?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your immediate issue by casting the object correctly:

```
//Note how we don't use the += operator, and we moved the cast:
playBoard[j-1][i-1][0] = (Integer)playBoard[j-1][i-1][0] + 1;
```

Or better yet, don't do any casting and as suggested in comments you should use a 2D array with a simple custom object:

```
//An example of a simple custom class/object
class CustomObject{
    public int number;
    public String string;

    CustomObject(int number, String string){
    this.number = number;
    this.string = string;
    }
}
```

And to use the custom class/object in a 2D array we can do this:

```
CustomObject board[][] = new CustomObject [10][10];

//generating mines. 
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        //Generate Brandon number
        int randonNumber = .....;

        //add new custom object with random number and with a blank string for now
        board[j][i] = new CustomObject(randonNumber, "");
    }
}
```

Then to change the value of your custom object we simply reference the inner variables however we like:

```
//Increment the number
board[6][2].number += 1;

//Getting/using the number
System.out.println("The value of the cell is " + board[6][2].number);

//Change the string:
board[6][2].string = "Test";

//Getting/using the string:
System.out.println("There are " + board[6][2].string + " mines in adjacent cells");
```

Comment: This is great thanks. I forget how useful objects are and need to implement them where I can more. This is a great solution and opens up a lot of ideas for me

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following article by Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting#primitive-vs-reference

Section 2 Primitive vs Reference gives a great understanding of what you are experiencing.

As for a solution, what are you gaining from the arrays being defined as Object? why not simplify to just making the array defined as int?

If you do this, you do not need to cast and you can do the simple += you are wanting.

As for improvement, you will need to gain a better understanding of utilizing Java's biggest strength - Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: I want to use the Object type because I need to store different primitive types. My first version was just an int type as you suggested and it worked fine, but I want the second index of the array to be strings. Hence the Object type. And yes I am currently taking OOP in school and I think there's a way I can do it using a seperate custom object, but this article is helpful. Thanks!